# IBM Worklight Console - audit trail of tasks performed on console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am using IBM Worklight 6 and for auditing purposes would like to know if I it is possible to log the details of tasks performed on the Worklight Console, i.e. log the details when deploying new version of app/adapter?

Regards,

Tom

Comment: if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

Worklight, or more specifically, the application server that Worklight Server is deployed to (WAS, WAS Liberty profile, Tomcat), does not have the ability to filter logs into seperate files, for example for the purpose you have mentioned.

What you might be able to do is take the server log, and create your own manual filtering (by script, of course). What you will need to do is to find the prefix for each action done and filter using it.

1. In Eclipse (or your production environment) open `server.xml > Logging` and change the Console log level from `Audit` (default) to `Info`.
2. This in turn will produce the following log lines in the sever log:

   > [INFO    ] FWLSE0084I: Adapter 'aaa' was deployed successfully. [project test]
3. In your script you can now filter for `FWLSE0084I` for adapters and similar prefixes for other actions, likely. I am not sure if all Worklight Console actions have prefixes, but if they are ones that require a connection to the server, then likely that they do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ0fj.png
[image]